# Template class with two types, inheritance and forward declaration

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I'm wrapping my head around this problem. I think it's actually not possible to do, but just to be sure I'd like to ask here if there actually is a solution.
Consider the following code. There are 2 templated classes A and B and two non-templated classes C and D which derive from A and B respectively.

```
// definition of class A
template <class DerivedA, class DerivedB> class A {
private:
    DerivedB data;
public:
    A(const DerivedB& data) : data(data) {}
    virtual ~A() {}
    DerivedB get() const { return data; }
};

// definition of class B
template <class DerivedA, class DerivedB> class B {
private:
    DerivedA data;
public:
    B(const DerivedA& data) : data(data) {}
    virtual ~B() {}
    DerivedA get() const { return data; }
};

// forward declaration of D
class D;

// definition of class C, derives from A<C, D>
class C : public A<C, D> {
private:
    int extraInfo;
public:
    C(const D& d) : A(d) {}
    virtual ~C() {}
    int getExtraInfo() const { return extraInfo; }
};

// definition of class D, derives from B<C, D>
class D : public B<C, D> {
private:
    int extraInfo;
public:
    D(const C& c) : B(c) {}
    virtual ~D() {}
    int getExtraInfo() const { return extraInfo; }
};
```

The problem here is that class C cannot be defined because class D is only forward declared. Hence, when the template A is written out then it doesn't know what its type for its private member is. Note that I cannot work with pointers, I need some known functionality. Is it in any way possible to compile such that I have my classes C and D?

Comment: What exactly prevents you from using pointers?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @YochaiTimmer I'm trying to implement a directed graph. class A represents a node and class B represents an arc. To actually use the directed graph with useful properties on the nodes and edges one should derive from the node class and the edge class. To circumvent `dynamic_cast` I try to use this templated approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way around this problem as you explain it and there should not be. As you have it now:

```
class C : public A<C, D>
```

means that `C` will inherit a data member of type `D`. In turn:

```
class D : public B<C, D>
```

means that `D` will inherit a data member of type `C`.

If `C` has a `D`, which has a `C`, which has a `D`... you have a nice infinite recursion, meaning in this case that the size of any `C` or `D` object will be infinite.

So, unless you use pointers (you can cut the infinite chain at any point inserting an appropriate null pointer) or references (you can reference a previously used object), you cannot and should not have this kind of classes.

Answer (score 1):

`C` inherits a member of type `D`, `D` inherits a member of type `C`. So, no, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can get away with this by making C and D implement a pure-virtual class, with the functionality you need (including getters), and making them pass that class as a template argument. You then do actually use a pointer to it in A and B, but you keep all the functionality.

Something like this (make your own adaptations)

```
// definition of class A
template <class DerivedA, class DerivedB> class A {
private:
    const DerivedB& _data;
public:
    A(const DerivedB& data) : _data(data) {}
    virtual ~A() {}
    DerivedB& get() const { return data; }
};

// definition of class B
template <class DerivedA, class DerivedB> class B {
private:
    DerivedA data;
public:
    B(const DerivedA& data) : data(data) {}
    virtual ~B() {}
    DerivedA get() const { return data; }
};

class TheInterface {
public:
    virtual int getExtraInfo() const = 0;
virtual ~TheInterface() = 0;
};

// definition of class C, derives from A<C, D>
class C : public TheInterface, public A<C, TheInterface> {
private:
    int extraInfo;
public:
    C(const TheInterface& d) : A(d) {}
    virtual ~C() {}
    int getExtraInfo() const { return extraInfo; }
};

// definition of class D, derives from B<C, D>
class D : public TheInterface, public B<C, D> {
private:
    int extraInfo;
public:
    D(const C& c) : B(c) {}
    virtual ~D() {}
    int getExtraInfo() const { return extraInfo; }
};
```